# AWS Lambda "Unable to import module 'handler': No module named handler"

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, lambda

AWS Lambda 'python2.7' can not find my module handler.

```
START RequestId: c6f97261-ba61-11e7-aeaf-bfb6aa28f7bb Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'handler': No module named handler

END RequestId: c6f97261-ba61-11e7-aeaf-bfb6aa28f7bb
REPORT RequestId: c6f97261-ba61-11e7-aeaf-bfb6aa28f7bb  Duration: 0.33 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 19 M
```

handler.py

```
def handler(event, context):
    return {'status': 'success'}
```

Folder structure:

- handler.py

Written on Windows 10, Deployed using serverless on Ubuntu VM from shared folder with host system. (virtualbox)

Comment: Well it seems that the module "handler" cannot be found! ... Jokes aside, please provide more information on the subject, why do you think it should be found? What are the steps you have done to make it not work? Have you any code that we could look at to find where the smell is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out this is a permission issue.
Running `chmod 644 handler.py` then redeploying fixed the issue.

In my case this was caused by deploying from a shared folder on my Ubuntu VM (Win10 host).
Shared folders have `rwxrwx---` permissions, which is not enough for AWS Lambda.
I needed to copy the folder and run `chmod` in the copied folder, then deploy from there.